# Show that the Lie algebra of $GL_n$ is $gl_n$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Here $GL_n$ is the set of all invertible $n\times n$ real matrices
with some other structure. Regard $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$,
the set of all $n\times n$ matrices,
as an $n^2$ dimensional real vector space,
a smooth manifold with standard differential structure.
Consider the determinant function
$\det_n:\mathbb R^{n\times n}\to \mathbb R$,
it's a smooth function, also it's continuous.
$\mathbb R-\{0\}$ is an open set in $\mathbb R$,
so $GL_n=\det_n^{-1}(\mathbb R)$ is an open submanifold of
$\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.
It's also a group with matrix multiplication,
in which multiplication and inverse maps
are smooth, so it's a Lie group.

And $gl_n$ is the set equal to $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$
with some other structure.
As I've shown above, it has a vector space structure.
Matrix multiplication makes it an associative algebra,
which concludes a Lie bracket.

As I've learnt, Lie groups can acts on itself by multiplycation.
For a Lie group $G$, note $l_g:G\to G,p\mapsto gp$,
considered as a left action for each $g\in G$.
A globle tangent vector fields $X$
satisfying $(l_g)_*X_p=X_{gp}$ for each $g,p\in G$
is called a left invariant tangent vector field.
All left invariant tangent vector fields can become into
a Lie subalgebra of $\Gamma^\infty(G,TG)$, noted as $L(G)$.
Because $X_p=(l_p)_*X_1$, where $1$ is the indentity of $G$,
it's easy to show that
vactor space $L(G)\cong T_1G\cong \mathbb R^n$,
where $n$ is the dimension of $G$.
So computing Lie algebras is computing Lie brackets.

It's easy to show
that $L(\mathbb R^n)\cong\mathbb R^n$ with $[X,Y]=0$,
and $L(S^1)\cong \mathbb R$ with $[X,Y]=0$.
It's hard to compute other examples.
I've computed that $L(GL_n)\cong gl_n$ by a not-so-strict way.
To do this, I used 2 theorems, which has been shown strictly.

\textbf{Thm.1.} For an $m$ dimensional smooth manifold $M$
and its coordinate card $\langle U,\varphi=(x_1,\cdots,x_m)\rangle$,
and an $n$ dimensional smooth manifold $N$
and its coordinate card $\langle V,\psi=(y_1,\cdots,y_m)\rangle$,
and a smooth germ $g$ of $N$ at $F(p)$,
and a map $F$ smooth at $p\in U$ satisfying $F(p)\in V$,
the tangent map $F_*:T_pM\to T_{F(p)}N$ satisfys that

$F_*\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_pg
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_p(g\circ F)
=\frac{\partial\left(g\circ F\circ\varphi^{-1}\ \right)}
{\partial x_j}\bigg|_p$

$=\displaystyle\sum_i
\frac{\partial\left(g\circ\psi^{-1}\ \right)}{\partial y_i}\bigg|_{F(p)}
\frac{\partial\left(y_i\circ F\circ\psi^{-1}\ \right)}
{\partial x_j}\bigg|_p
=\displaystyle\sum_i
\frac{\partial\left(y_i\circ F\circ\psi^{-1}\ \right)}
{\partial x_j}\bigg|_p
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\bigg|_{F(p)}g$

So the matrix of $F_*$ is the Jacobian matrix,
with basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_p\right\}_j$
and $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\bigg|_{F(p)}\right\}_i$.

\textbf{Thm.2.} For For an $m$ dimensional smooth manifold $M$
and its coordinate card $\langle U,\varphi=(x_1,\cdots,x_m)\rangle$,
I note $\partial_k:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$.
For $X=\displaystyle\sum_k a_k\partial_k,
Y=\displaystyle\sum_l b_l\partial_l$,
and $p\in U$, $f$ a smooth germ at $p$,

$[X,Y]_pf=\displaystyle\sum_{k,l}
a_k(p)\partial_k|_p(b_l\partial_lf)-b_l(p)\partial_l|_p(a_k\partial_kf)$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{k,l}\left
(a_k(p)(\partial_k|_pb_l)\partial_l|_pf)
+a_k(p)b_l(p)\partial_k|_p\partial_lf
-b_l(p)(\partial_l|_pa_k)\partial_k|_pf
-b_l(p)a_k(p)\partial_l|_p\partial_kf)\right)$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{k,l}(
a_k(\partial_kb_l)\partial_l-b_l(\partial_la_k)\partial_k)_pf$

The 2 theorems above are proved strictly,
but the computing below is not. Here's my computing.

$GL_n$ is an open submanifold of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.
Note $\partial_{i,j}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i,j}}$.
For a matrix $M\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$,
note $M_{i,j}$ as the element in the i-th row, the j-th column,
note $M=(M_{i,j})_{i,j}$. For $M,p\in GL_n$,
$\frac{\partial(Mp)_{i,j}}{\partial p_{k,l}}
=\displaystyle\sum_r\frac{\partial M_{i,r}p_r,j}{\partial p_{k,l}}
=\delta_l^jM_{i,k}$, so $(l_M)_*\partial_{k,l}|_p
=\displaystyle\sum_iM_{i,k}\partial_{i,l}|_{Mp}$.

For $X=\displaystyle\sum_{k,l}x_{k,l}\partial_{k,l}
\in\Gamma^\infty(GL_n,TGL_n)$,
and $M,p\in GL_n$, $(l_M)_*X_p
=\displaystyle\sum_{k,l}x_{k,l}(p)\sum_iM_{i,k}\partial_{i,l}|_{Mp}
=\displaystyle\sum_{i,l}
\left(\displaystyle\sum_kM_{i,k}x_{k,l}(p)\right)\partial_{i,l}|{Mp}$.
For $v=\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}\partial_{i,j}|_p$, note $[v]=(a_{i,j})_{i,j}$,
then $[(l_M)_*X_p]=M[X_p]$. $X\in L(GL_n)$ iff $[X_{Mp}]=M[X_p]$.
Then $[X_p]=p[X_I]$, where $I$ is the identity metrix.

Suppose $X,Y\in GL_n$ that
$[X_I]=(a_{i,j})_{i,j}=:A,[Y_I]=(b_{k,l})_{k,l}=:B$,
then $\partial_{i,j}[X]_{k,l}
=\displaystyle\sum_r
\frac{\partial p_{i,r}a_{r,j}}{\partial p_{k,l}}
=\delta_k^ia_{l,j},\partial_{k,l}[Y]_{i,j}
=\displaystyle\sum_s
\frac{\partial p_{k,s}b_{s,l}}{\partial p_{i,j}}
=\delta_i^kb_{j,l}$.
Then $[X,Y]_p
=\displaystyle\sum_{i,j,r,l}p_{i,r}a_{r,j}b_{j,l}\partial_{i,l}
-\displaystyle\sum_{k,l,s,j}p_{k,s}b_{s,l}a_{l,j}\partial_{k,j}$,
that is, $[[X,Y]_p]=p(AB-BA)$. Thus $L(GL_n)\cong gl_n$.

My computing is shown above, but it's not so strict,
because I use tangent vector fields of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$
but not $GL_n$.
The answer is right, but the method is not strict.
And this method cannot compute $L(SL_n)$ and stuff.
Could you please give me a more strict, more general way
to compute Lie algebras of Lie groups?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3090558/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1151421/96384, and probably others.